# How to check if there is a key in collection that has more than one value?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, mapreduce

My collection looks something like this:

```
{
  {
    _id: 'some value',
    'product/productId': 'some value',
    'product/title': 'some value',
    'product/price': 'unknown'
  },
  {
    _id: 'some value',
    'product/productId': 'some value',
    'product/title': 'some value',
    'product/price': '12.57'
  }
}
```

My goal is to find if there are any products that have more than one price. Values of the key "product/price" can be "unknown" or numerical (e.g. "12.75"). Is there a way to write an aggregation pipeline for that or do I need to use a map-reduce algorithm? I tried both options but didn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you can try this aggregation pipeline:

First of all, the `_id` field is (or should be) unique, so I think you mean another field like `id`.

So the trick is to group by that `id` and get all prices into an array. Then filter using `$match` to get only documents where the total of prices is greater than 1.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$id",
      "price": {
        "$push": "$product/price"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$gt": [ { "$size": "$price" }, 1 ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w6x871Aw9Xp)

As added into comments for Joe if you want consider identical values as the same you have to use [$addToSet](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/)

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wJ_gbjDBho4)

Comment: Use `$addToSet` instead of `$push` to consider identical values the same.

Comment: Yes, `_id` field is unique and set by mongo itself. When I run your code and change `push` to `addToSet` it prints out column "price" with value of 1291 elements. Does it mean there are 1291 documents in collection containing more than one value for the key "price" or something else?

Comment: It means that there are 1291 different prices for that specific `id`.